# "unable to download application" when installing directly on iPhone

Tags: ios-appstore, iphone

While trying to download an app over a wifi connection, app store told me that it was "unable to download application, please connect to pc to download application".
After doing some research i found it was not a common problem and this morning over 3G the application has now downloaded.

My question being, is there an issue with the wifi network restricting me (maybe i have to many Wi-fi connections or something) or does it have something to do with the fact that i haven't downloaded iOS 5 yet?

Comment: I've removed the second question ("is the 3GS fast enough for iOS 5"), please ask an additional question for this if needed

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of variables that could be the cause here (iOS 5 would be the problem if the app required it, but Apple has a different dialog box for that.)

1. Network time out (My firewall at work didn't like Apple's CDN until I manually approved  it)
2. Small hiccup (Has it happened multiple times? )
3. Hiccup on Apple's end (timeout?)

Next time it happens, I'd recommend either turning Airplane mode on and then back off and trying again (basically resetting all the network connections).  I've seen that happen before (especially with larger downloads).  The large download situation wouldn't apply here since you mentioned it did download over 3G